# Cardinality and Natural Density of Iterated function results Set

Tags: number-theory

Let's use **2x+3** as our [iterated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function).

Start from 1, we get SIF<sub>1</sub>: 1, 5, 13, 29, 61, 125...

Start from 3, we get SIF<sub>3</sub>: 3, 9, 21, 45, 93, 189...

Start from 7, we get SIF<sub>7</sub>: 7, 17, 37, 77, 157...

We cannot start from 5, because 5 already belongs to SIF<sub>1</sub>. So, we say SIF<sub>1</sub> is valid, but SIF<sub>5</sub> is not valid. Then, clearly any 2 **valid** SIF<sub>n</sub> and SIF<sub>m</sub> sets are **disjoint**.

What are the [Cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) and the [Natural Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of any given SIF<sub>n</sub>?

I think Cardinality is ℵ<sub>0</sub> since the set is infinite and countable.

And I think the Natural Density is 0, since the values grow exponentially. If we use SIF<sub>3</sub> as an example, the a(n)/n goes: 2/10 (0.2), 5/100 (0.05), 8/1000 (0.008), 11/10000 (0.0011) - clearly a(n)/n → 0 as n → ∞.

Now, let's extend the sets by another iterated function **2x**, applied to each element in the set SIF<sub>n</sub>.

For example, let's use SIF<sub>3</sub> to get SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>3</sub> (I will stop calculating numbers at >1000 in both directions, ... means *ad infinitum*):

| 3 | 9 | 21 | 45 | 93 | 189 | 381 | 765 | 1533 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 18 | 42 | 90 | 186 | 378 | 762 | 1530 | ... | ... |
| 12 | 36 | 84 | 180 | 372 | 756 | 1524 | ... | ... | ... |
| 24 | 72 | 172 | 360 | 744 | 1512 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 48 | 144 | 344 | 720 | 1488 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 96 | 288 | 688 | 1440 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 192 | 576 | 1376 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 384 | 1152 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 768 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1536 | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The Cardinality remains the same, as for the Natural Density, the a(n)/n now goes: 3/10 (0.3), 14/100 (0.14), 36/1000 (0.036) - so we again clearly have a(n)/n → 0 as n → ∞.

So far so good. Now let's start joining these SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>n</sub> sets in the following way.

We will start with **SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub>**.

We take **SIF<sub>1</sub>**: 1, 5, 13, 29, 61, 125... and for each element **n** of SIF<sub>1</sub>, we join **SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub>** with **SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>2n+1</sub>**.

So, given SIF<sub>1</sub>: 1, 5, 13, 29, 61, 125... we will be joining SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub> with SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>3</sub>, SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>11</sub>, SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>27</sub>, SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>59</sub>, SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>123</sub>, SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>251</sub>... which are all **valid**, btw.

Let's name this new set, the set of all elements from all joined SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>n</sub> sets, as **2D_SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub>**, because we started with **SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub>** and basically added a dimmension onto it.

Cardinality of **2D_SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub>** is of course ℵ<sub>0</sub>, but I have no idea what the Natural Density is.

My suspision is that the Natural Density is still 0, but I don't know how to tackle calculating it without using a computer and coding it up. *Which I can do*, **but I am more intersted in a mathematical solution**.

Especially, since this process can be repeated to get **3D_SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub>**, where we look at each joined set, and add a dimmension on to **each of those**. So, for example, where we joined in SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>3</sub>, where SIF<sub>3</sub> is 3, 9, 21... we now join in SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>7</sub>, SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>19</sub>, SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>43</sub>, ... respectively. And we repeat for each joined set.

And again we can repeat, to add yet another dimmension to each of those joined sets. So, where we joined in SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>7</sub>, where SIF<sub>7</sub> is 7, 17, 37... we now join in SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>15</sub>, SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>35</sub>, SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>75</sub>, ... respectively - to get **4D_SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub>**.

This process can be repeated again and again, each time adding yet another dimmension to the set, and this is where we get to the main question.

The Cardinality will of course remain ℵ<sub>0</sub>, *that much is trivial*.

**But what about the Natural Density of ND_SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub> as N → ∞?**
Does it go to **1**?

It *feels* like it should.

It feels like as N → ∞ then ND_SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub> → **ℕ**. Or in words, as N goes to infinity, the set ND_SIF<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub> becomes equivalent to the set of [Natural Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number).

This I definitely cannot code up :) - so maths is the only possible solution... but I do not know how to attack this problem.

Comment: I did some calculations, but the limits of my programming are low and their confirmation is faaaaaar from enough :(

Comment: *"Then, clearly any 2 valid SIFn and SIFm sets are disjoint."* Why did you skip over SIF$_2$? It starts with $2, 7, ...$ and so SIF$_7$ should be invalid.

Comment: I tried testing the hypotesys that the limit set is all the natural. I tested all the numbers up to $1000000$. If I haven't done any mistake $$ 524288 \notin \bigcup_{l \in \mathbb{N}_0} \mathbf{{SIF}^2_{2l+1}}$$ As this set contains the limit set this would mean that $\lim_N \mathbf{ND\_{SIF}^2_1} \ne \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Stef My mistake in forgetting to specify that we only care about odd numbers for SIFs - even numbers will be covered in the vertical x2 step

Comment: @Marco 524288 is a power of 2 - 2^19... all powers of 2 are in the very first column of the very first SIF1... remember that in each SIF we have the first row of odd numbers, and then vertically we repeat x2 infinitely in each column

Comment: @PredragStojadinović right, there was a mistake in the program. I stopped one power of $2$ to early.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer. It provides the natural density for all the "finite dimensional" sets and an explicit description of the set $\mathbf{{SIF}^2_{2l+1}}$ so i think it can be usefull

Let call $a_n=2a_{n-1}+3$, $a_0=l \in \mathbb{N}$. The set $\mathbf{{SIF}_l}=\{ a_n\}$. Let write
$$
a(x):= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n 
$$
you have
$$
(1-2x) a(x)= l+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-2a_{n-1}) x^n = l+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=l+\frac{3x}{1-x}
$$
so
$$
a(x)=\frac{l+(3-l)x}{(1-x)(1-2x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(2^n(l+3)-3\right)x^n
$$
By comparing the Taylor series you  obtain
$$
\mathbf{{SIF}_l}=\{2^n(l+3)-3 : n \in \mathbb{N}_0\} 
$$
Similarly, if you call $b_n=2 b_{n-1}$, $b_0=c$ and $b(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k$ you obtain
$$
b(x)=\frac{c}{1-2x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2^kc) x^k
$$
With this you can obtain
$$
\mathbf{{SIF}^2_{2l+1}}=\{ 2^k \left(2^{n+1}(l+2)-3\right) : n,k \in \mathbb{N}_0\}
$$

Now let's call $a_2(m)$ the cardinality of the elements of $\mathbf{2D\_{SIF}^2_1}$ less or equal than $m$.

We have $a_2(m)=O((\log(m+3))^3)$. In particular, the natural density of $\mathbf{2D\_{SIF}^2_1}$ is $0$. Indeed
$$
\mathbf{2D\_{SIF}^2_1}= \bigcup_{l \in \mathbf{{SIF}_1} \cup \{0\}} \mathbf{{SIF}^2_{2l+1}}
$$
If we call $|\mathbf{SIF}_1|_m$ the number of elements of the set $\mathbf{SIF}_1$ that are less than equal than $m$ we obtain
$$
|\mathbf{SIF}_1|_m \le \log_2(m+3)-1
$$
while
$$
| \mathbf{{SIF}^2_{2l+1}}|_m \le (\log_2(m)+1) \log_2\left(\frac{m+3}{(l+2)}\right) = O\left((\log(m+3))^2\right)
$$
so
$$
a_2(m) \le ( |\mathbf{SIF}_1|_m  +1)| |\mathbf{{SIF}^2_{2l+1}}|_m=O\left((\log(m+3))^3\right)
$$
More generally, if you call $a_N(m)$ the number of elements of $\mathbf{N\_{SIF}_1^2} $ you should have $a_N(m)=O((\log(m+3))^{M})$ for some $M>N$ and so the natural density should be $0$ for any $N$.

Comment: Not sure I understood most of it :( For example, how do Taylor series come into play, here?

Comment: @PredragStojadinović Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_functions) can help. I found the generating function of the sequence $\mathbf{{SIF}_l}$ and expand in a Taylor series such function. By definition of generating function, the terms of the sequence are the coefficients of the Taylor expansion

Answer (score -1):

This is very brute and informal but too much for a comment :

Consider Sif_n

Assume all k < n have occured for all valid Sif_i with i < n.

Then the union of all elements in Sif_i for all i < n have sieved out about the density of

2^v (n-1) integers.

Considering mod n this implies that once again we are sieving at least roughly the powers of 2 times n.

IF on the other hand only a small amount of numbers have occured less than n , we still get about roughly the powers of 2 times n.

So the " past " makes little difference.
This is a consequence of not allowing starting points that have already occured and the exponential growth rates.

Comment: I see a downvote. Did I misunderstand the question or did I make a mistake ? It is just a comment.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but i think it is because it lacks of clarity. I onestly didn't understood your point.

Comment: @Marco thanks for the feedback. I will think about a reformulation.